# How can I fix these creases on my mesh?

Tags: mesh, shaders

My problem is:
My mesh has these shading errors but I can't find any double vertices or double faces. I tried using "Merge by Distance", but it didn't work.
Can someone help??? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Have you tried recalculating the normals?

Comment: Also: can you show a picture of the object in edit mode so we can see what the topology looks like?

Comment: Thank you. some of my faces were flipped. I recalculated normals.